# How to use Authentication with JIRA REST API in Java

Tags: java, rest, https, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

hi im creating a simple tool using java to create,update and delete issues(tickets) in jira. i am using rest api **following code** is im using to authenticate jira and issue tickets.

```
 public class JiraConnection {


public static URI jiraServerUri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/api/2/issue/HSP-1/");

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();

    final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,"vinuvish92@gmail.com","vinu1994");
    System.out.println("Sending issue creation requests...");
    try {
        final List<Promise<BasicIssue>> promises = Lists.newArrayList();
        final IssueRestClient issueClient = restClient.getIssueClient();

        System.out.println("Sending issue creation requests...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            final String summary = "NewIssue#" + i;
            final IssueInput newIssue = new IssueInputBuilder("TST", 1L, summary).build();
            System.out.println("\tCreating: " + summary);
            promises.add(issueClient.createIssue(newIssue));
        }
        System.out.println("Collecting responses...");
        final Iterable<BasicIssue> createdIssues = transform(promises, new Function<Promise<BasicIssue>, BasicIssue>() {
            @Override
            public BasicIssue apply(Promise<BasicIssue> promise) {
                return promise.claim();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Created issues:\n" + Joiner.on("\n").join(createdIssues));
    } finally {
        restClient.close();
    }
}
```

}

according this code i couldn't connect to the jira

**following exception i am getting **
[image: Screen shoot of exception]

> please suggest me best solution to do my task

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your error is clearly related to url parameter. The incriminated line and the fact that the error message is about not finding the resource are good indications of it.

You don't need to input the whole endpoint since you are using the JiraRestClient. Depending on the method that you call it will resolve the endpoint. Here is an example that works: as you can see I only input the base url

[image]